# AMQP consumer(listener adapter + SimpleMessageListenerContainer) holding message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Recently we came across a situation where the messages were taken up from the queue by the consumer but did not reach the listener bound to that queue. We were able to make this assertion because we have an interceptor on our listeners (which prints a log message) that was not triggered for those messages. As soon as we restarted the server(tomcat) the messages were consumed and acked.

We would like to know the reason for such a behavior. We analyzed the thread dumps but with no success.

Comment: Would be great to see config and DEBUG logs on the matter. And in logs point us out, please, where you are sure that messages should be consumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such issues are invariably caused by one of two problems:

- container thread(s) "stuck" in user code
- some network component (e.g. router) silently closing a connection that it thinks is idle such the the client and/or server is not aware that the connection is closed.

You seem to have eliminated the first (assuming your analysis is correct) so it's most likely the second.

You can enable heartbeats on the connection to avoid the network thinking a connection is idle. Refer to the RabbitMQ documentation.

Comment: Hi Gary, We have heartbeat set on our connection and we are certain that this is not the case as the other listeners on this connection are working perfectly fine. It is only with certain queues that the messages are getting stuck and as said these messages have reached the consumer side but have not been received by the listener. We will have a look at the thread dumps once again as you point out there are only two reasons for such a behavior.